# Debian 9: install php5.3.1 which is not available on apt-get

Tags: php, debian

I need the old php5.3.1 version but you can't download it from : `apt-get install php5.3.1`

I have few notion in debian (or unix system in general). Is there another way to get it?

Comment: You shouldn't use PHP 5.3 for anything - **anything** - that you'll put on the public Internet.

Comment: I know, but I have no choice here. anyway, if someone need it, here is an easy way for 5.6 (best I have found): https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/

Comment: "I have no choice here" is making the choice to get hacked.

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3 is old. I mean, *really* old. 5.3.10 is from **2012**, and the latest 5.3 release from **2014**. No way to find it precompiled and just "apt-get install"-ready in Debian 9.

The only way i can think of is to build and install it manually: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381687/79673

Good luck

Answer (score -2):

Try to use command `sudo` before your command for executing this on administrator mode.

Comment: Thx, but the issue isn't the fact that I use admin mode, php5.3.10 is no more in apt-get. So I need to find another way to get it!

Comment: Can you get the last version of PHP 7 or do you need the 5.3.1 version ?

Comment: For now php5.3.10, I will use php7 in the next step of the project